# I want to print prime numbers in php up to 200

Tags: php

My attempt at a list of prime numbers:

```
$num = 100;  

for( $j = 2; $j <= $num; $j++ ) { 
    for( $k = 2; $k < $j; $k++ ) { 
        if( $j % $k == 0 ) { 
            break; 
        }
```

What else do I need to do?

Comment: very easy:- https://eval.in/735185

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this you didn't echo the variable the command isn't complete

```
<?php
//See is a list of primer number below 
$num =200;

for( $j = 2; $j <= $num; $j++ )
{
for( $k = 2; $k < $j; $k++ )
{
if( $j % $k == 0 )
{
break;
}

}
if( $k == $j )
echo "Prime Number : ", $j, "<br>";
}
?>
```